# Comparison of preprocessor variables

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

What is the reason why this code does not compile?

```
#define THREADMODEL ASC 

#if THREADMODEL==NOASC
// This block should be ignored and the code should compile
#error
#endif

int main() {
}
```

Comment: Alternative: #define THREADMODEL_ASC    #ifdef THREADMODEL_ASC               Second Alternative: #define THREADMODEL_ASC 1     #if THREADMODEL_ASC

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the preprocessor interprets

```
#if THREADMODEL==NOASC
```

it will replace `THREADMODEL` with `ASC`:

```
#if ASC==NOASC
```

Unless you have `#define`d `ASC` and `NOASC` to have numeric values, the preprocessor will replace them with 0 values (it takes any undefined symbols and replaces them with 0):

```
#if 0==0
```

This then evaluates to `1` and so the preprocessor will evaluate the block.

To fix this, try giving different numeric values to `ASC` and `NOASC`, like this:

```
#define ASC    0
#define NOASC  (1 + (ASC))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's best to fully parenthesize macro definitions that expand to expressions: `#define NOASC (1 + ASC)`

Comment: @KeithThompson Good catch - I remembered to parenthesize `ASC`, but not the resulting expression.

Comment: In fact you don't need to parenthesize `ASC` (assuming it's defined properly itself). You do need to parenthesize macro arguments, but `ASC` is another macro, not an argument to `NOASC`.

Comment: @KeithThompson While you're right that it's not necessary, I've gotten burned a couple of times by people writing bad define constants and figured the extra parentheses couldn't hurt but might actually help.